# How do I keep using the Google Talk Plugin after it's deprecated?

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts, google-talk, voip

Google is deprecating the Google Talk Plugin which is the basis of the legacy soft phone in Gmail, and replacing it with a Hangouts based (HTML5) soft phone. Unfortunately the new phone is garbage (poor audio quality, lousy echo cancellation, frequent disconnections).

Presuming that the actual server API used by the Google Talk Plugin is not being deprecated, how can I keep using the plugin for calling phones? Is it possible to construct a page that embeds it and provides a dialer?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you can't. Google Talk is completely dead.